# Ids incremented twice during import-export (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using Django-import-export library, I am facing problem while uploading data in json/csv file. when I upload data file via django-admin, id field increases twice? how to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django-import-export post\_save called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124600/django-import-export-post-save-called-twice)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an [admin resource](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html) like this

```
class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        import_id_fields = ['id', or 'ID' or whatever it is in your csv file column header. Or comment out this option if your import file has no column header for id]
        #skip_unchanged = True
        #report_skipped = True
```

And then in the admin class for your model:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = MyModelResource
```

You may also want to experiment with the [IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS#import-export-use-transactions) setting.